# How to record hardware and software info in Julia?

Tags: reproducibility, julia

[Watermark](https://github.com/rasbt/watermark) extension for Jupyter shows system and package information for reproducibility:

```
CPython 3.7.1
IPython 7.8.0

numpy 1.17.2
scipy 1.3.1
sklearn 0.21.3

compiler   : Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)
system     : Darwin
release    : 18.7.0
machine    : x86_64
processor  : i386
CPU cores  : 12
interpreter: 64bit
Git hash   : 7b29998a4d445f01664683db656c40158a6b5dee
```

Is there a tool for Julia to achieve the same result in JupyterLab (or REPL at least)?

Answer (score 6):

I would've posted this in a comment, but I unfortunately don't have enough reputation.

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42610074/9796552) should provide enough to help you achieve what you want.

In short, you can use Julia's `Sys` module which contains functions dedicated to retrieving system information.

Comment: And the Manifest.toml has all of the package versions. Together that's the OP's answer.